# Tomar datos desde una session

Tags: php

**ACTUALIZADO**

Hice un cambio para poder trabajar mejor con sesiones.

Base de datos productos

```
id  userid  producto        valor
4   1       bicicleta r20   5000
5   2       bicicleta TT    6500
```

Base de datos usuario

```
id  nombre      pass
1   pedro       pedro1234
2   juan        juan1234
```

Archivo PHP

```
<p><a href="leer-UNO.php">Precompra</a> <a href="salir.php">Salir</a></p>
<?php

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM productos");

if ($sql->rowCount() > 0){ 
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {

?>
<p>#<?=$row['id'];?> - <?=$row['producto'];?> - <?=$row['valor'];?> - <a href="leer-UNO.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>">Comprar</a></p>
<?php
}
} else {
?>
<p>Producto(s) no existe...</p>
<?php
} 
?>
?>
```

En este archivo tomo el id desde la session, pero mi problema es que no se mantiene guardad, si quiero ver que producto elegi me da como error `No hay produtos`.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){

    $productID = $_REQUEST['id'];

$producto = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = '".$productID."'");

$row = $producto->fetch();

?>

<?=$row['producto'];?> - $<?=$row['valor'];?>

<?php

} else {
echo 'No hay produtos';
}
?>
```

> Los puntos por resolver son 2:
>
> 1 - Cuando el uaurio hace una precompra, pueda elegir la cantidad (son bicicletas, no creo que supere a uno) y que esta quede guardada temporalmente y poder verla despues.
>
> 2 - Aprender el uso se sessiones ya que solo las utilizo para logue de usuarios.

Gracias!

Comment: En el select te hace falta el WHERE id = $_COOKIE['id']

Comment: y si tomo la variable `$dato`? por que `$_COOKIE['ID']` me da error

Comment: Hiciste el inicio de sesión en tu pagina en la cual haces la lectura del valor mostrador con  session_start(); ? [enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Lo habia hecho pero tampoco funcionaba

Comment: La pregunta no es clara:  los puntos `1` y `3` que expones al final son confusos y aparentemente contradictorios. El punto `2` tampoco es claro, ¿es parte del contexto de este problema o se trata de un problema aparte que por lo tanto debería tratarse en una pregunta aparte? Aunque tenga una jugosa recompensa, la pregunta podría ser a posteriori candidata para cierre, sea porque no es clara, sea porque es demasiado amplia.

Comment: Si se pudiera, yo votaria por cerrar esta pregunta ya que esta buscando soluciones a la implementación completa de un **carro de compras**, y desde mi punto de vista, eso se basa en opiniones y/o es demasiado amplia. No hay ningún tipo de lineamientos explicito, lo cual se presta a multiples soluciones.

Comment: Tres preguntas en una...

Comment: Mil diculpas, estoy de acuerdo con cerrar la pregunta. Gracias de todos modos!

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Marcos. Una cosa es solucionar una duda en concreto y otra desarrollar un escenario entero, por mucha recompensa que tenga...

Comment: No queria un escenario entero, solo tomar los datos por sessiones y listo. Aprender como se manejan bien las sessiones porque solo las uso cuando un usuario se logue. Por eso intente hacerlo con cookies, pero no tenia resultado.

Comment: PAra buscar una respuesta canonica, deberias tener una pregunta canonica. Cual seria esa pregunta aca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una sesión es un mecanismo para persistir información en  diferentes páginas web para identificar usuarios mientras estos navegan un sitio o app. Te preguntarás por qué las sesiones son necesarias en un sitio web. Para ver porqué las sesiones son necesarias, tenemos que viajar atrás y ver como esta diseñado el protocolo HTTP.

El protocolo HTTP es un protocolo sin estado, lo que significa que no hay forma de que un servidor recuerde a un usuario específico entre múltiples peticiones. Por ejemplo, cuando accedes a una página web, el servidor sólo es responsable de proveer el contenido de la página solicitada. Así que cuando accedes a otras páginas en el mismo sitio web, el servidor web interpreta cada petición separadamente, como si no estuvieran relacionadas unas con otras. No hay forma para el servidor de sane que cada petición fue originada por el mismo usuario.

**¿Cómo iniciar una Sesión?**

En esta sección, discutiremos cómo iniciar una sesión en PHP.

Cuando quieras tratar con variables de sesión, necesitas asegurarte de que la sesión ya haya empezado. Hay varias formas de iniciar una sesión en PHP.
Usa la Función `session_start`.

Este será el método que verás más a menudo, cuando la sesión es iniciada mediante la función `session_start`.

```
<?php
// start a session
session_start();

// manipular session con variables
?>
```

**Cómo obtener un identificador de Sesión?**

Como discutimos anteriormente, el servidor crea un número único para cada nueva sesión. Si quieres obtener el identificador de sesión, puedes usar la función `session_id`, como muestra el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

Esto debería darte el identificador de sesión actual. La función session_id es interesante en porque también puede recibir un argumento— un identificador de sesión. Si quieres reemplazar el identificador de sesión generado por el sistema por el tuyo propio, puedes suministrarlo como el primer argumento de la función `session_id`.

```
<?php
session_id(YOUR_SESSION_ID);
session_start();
?>
```

Es importante hacer notar que la función `session_id` debe estar situada antes que la llamada a `session_start` cuando quieras iniciar una sesión con un identificador de sesión personalizado.

**¿Cómo Crear Variables de Sesión?**

En esta sección, exploraremos cómo inicializar variables de sesión en PHP.

Como discutimos anteriormente, una vez que una sesión es iniciada, el array super-global `$_SESSION` es inicializado con la correspondiente información de sesión. Por defecto, se inicializa con un array vacío, y puedes almacenar más información usando un par clave-valor.

Veamos el siguiente script de ejemplo que muestra cómo inicializar las variables de sesión.

```
<?php
// start a session
session_start();

// variables session
$_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'] = '1';
$_SESSION['logged_in_user_name'] = 'Tutsplus';

echo $_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'];
echo $_SESSION['logged_in_user_name'];
?>
```

Como puedes ver, hemos iniciado una sesión al principio del script usando la función `session_start`. A continuación, hemos inicializado un par de variables de sesión. Finalmente, hemos accedido a dichas variables usando la super-global `$_SESSION`.

**¿Cómo Destruir una Sesión?**

En esta sección, veremos cómo puedes destruir una sesión. Si quieres eliminar toda la información relacionada con la sesión, puedes usar la función `session_destroy`.

Intentemos entender cómo funciona usando el siguiente ejemplo.

```
<?php
// start a session
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

La función `session_destroy` elimina todo lo que se almacena en la sesión actual. Por lo tanto, verás la variable `$_SESSION` vacía en las subsecuentes peticiones ya que la función `session_destroy` eliminó todos los datos de sesión almacenados en disco.

Generalmente, usarás la función `session_destroy` cuando el usuario va a ser desconectado.

> Lo que veo es solo vas a tener un producto y no es necesario usar sesiones para tal si solo es un producto y no carrito de compras en donde puede tener mas de uno.
>   Yo creo que tendrias que pasar los datos por `GET` y listo.

Answer (score 2):

Te respondo en orden inverso.

> 2 - Aprender el uso de sesiones ya que solo las utilizo para que los
>   usuarios inicien sesión.

Las sesiones como concepto son un sistema que permite guardar una colección de datos temporales en el servidor asociados normalmente a una cookie que se genera automáticamente para cada navegador (PHPSESSID normalmente).

Puedes utilizarlo para que cada navegador que pasea por tu web tenga variables con valores específicos para él.

Esto suele servir para datos temporales en la misma navegación de una persona.

Por ejemplo, el carrito de la compra de un anónimo.

Los datos se almacenan bajo un esquema de clave/valor: `$_SESSION['clave'] = valor;`.

Para poder utilizar una sesión debes hacer un `session_start()` que inicia el contexto que carga dicha sesión para disponer de la colección de `$_SESSION`.

Ten en cuenta que las sesiones tienen una caducidad que ocurre después de 24 minutos de inactividad (se puede cambiar por configuración).

> 1 - Cuando el usuario hace una precompra, pueda elegir la cantidad
>   (son bicicletas, no creo que supere a uno) y que esta quede guardada
>   temporalmente y poder verla después.

En este caso no necesitas utilizar sesiones, ya que con enviarte el dato a la siguiente pantalla es suficiente.

```
<form action="leer-UNO.php">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id'];?>">
#<?=$row['id'];?> - <?=$row['producto'];?> - <?=$row['valor'];?> - 

<input type="number" name="cantidad"> <!-- Puedes también utilizar un select -->

<button>Comprar</button>

</form>
```

Esto llamaría a tu rutina de `leer-UNO.php` con los datos en `$_REQUEST['id']`  y `$_REQUEST['cantidad']`.

En el caso de que quieras que los datos se recuerden para peticiones posteriores, lo único que tienes que hacer donde sea es lo siguiente:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
$_SESSION['cantidad'] = $_REQUEST['cantidad'];
```

A partir de estas líneas los datos se conservarán para el mismo navegador desde cualquier página PHP que utilices.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día te voy a echar la mano con lo de la sesiones:
1 Tu conexión 
2.Tu login

Creo que esto no tienes problema,  en un sistema que estoy desarrollando para poder utilizar las session´s por recomendación de mi coach hice un archivo para crear las variables de session, en este solo te pongo este código para una variable:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['conectado']="si";

$_SESSION['USUARIO']=$resultado[$i]->getCadenaApellido1()." ".$resultado[$i]->getCadenaApellido2()." ".$resultado[$i]->getCadenaNombre();
```

Esto lo que hace es traer de la consulta los datos relacionados del usuario del sistema lo que me permite imprimir su nombre completo en donde yo quiera con solo invocarlo.

Para tener el control de acceso a tus archivos que lo requieran por seguridad basta con añadir estas lineas por ejemplo si tienes una pagina principal o menú como es mi caso:

```html
<?php
        include_once "master/html/html_cabecera_menu_inc.php";
?>
<?php 
    /* inicio de la sesion */
    session_start(); 
   /* Si no hay una sesion creada,se redirecciona al index */
    if(empty($_SESSION['USUARIO'])) 
     { header("Location:login.php");}
?>
```

En caso que alguien escriba la ruta del menú, si no tiene sesión abierta lo redirecciona al login

Para cualquier otra sección de tu sistema que requieras que este el "logeado" o sesión abierta por seguridad estas lineas bastan siempre al inicio del archivo php.

```html
<?php 
 session_start();  
?>
```

En caso de que la sección donde lo escribas no requiera tener la session incluida te regresa un mensaje de error comentando que tienes duplicada la instrucción.

Si bien no es una explicación de la A a la Z espero te sirva de algo.

Saludos